# Continuous mapping Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I want to show that $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \int_\Theta q(\theta) \log\frac{p(\theta\mid X^N)}{\mathcal{N}(\theta\mid\theta_0,N^{-1}I(\theta))} \, d\theta = 0.$$ I know that $p(\theta\mid X^N) \rightarrow \mathcal{N}(\theta\mid \theta_0, N^{-1}I(\theta))$ w.p $1$. And using continuous mapping theorem $|\log (p(\theta\mid X^N))- \log(\mathcal{N}(\theta\mid\theta_0,N^{-1}I(\theta)))| \rightarrow 0$ w.p $1$.

I want to use the argument that since for large $N$   $$\ \ \log\frac{p(\theta\mid X^N)}{\mathcal{N}(\theta\mid\theta_0,N^{-1}I(\theta))}< \varepsilon \Rightarrow \int_ \Theta q(\theta) \log\frac{p(\theta\mid X^N)}{\mathcal{N}(\theta\mid \theta_0,N^{-1} I(\theta))} \, d\theta < \varepsilon \int_\Theta q(\theta) \, d\theta = \varepsilon.$$ Hence my proposition is correct.

Comment: Note the proper use of \lim and \log and \mid, and the fact that a small space precedes $d\theta$ or $dx$, etc., as in my edits. If you write $A\lim f(x)$ it doesn't look like $A lim f(x),$ not only because $\lim$ is not italicized but also you see the right spacing to the left of $\lim,$ and you'll find that the spacing depends on the context. Similarly with $\log$ And $A|B$ doesn't look the same as $A\mid B.$ And in a "displayed" (as opposed to "inline") context you see $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty}$ rather than $\lim_{N\to\infty}. \qquad$

Comment: Thanks! Will follow these from next time.